# Failing to persist data with spring JpaRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Ive created a simple 3 entities data model and when trying to persist data its not working.
Here are the entities and their id classes, server:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Server {

    @Id
    private String name;

    private String serverUrl;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "server", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Service> services;
}
```

Service:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ServiceId.class)
public class Service {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Server server;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "service", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Container> containers;
}

public class ServiceId implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    private Server server;
}
```

Container:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ContainerId.class)
public class Container {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Service service;

    private String command;
    private String state;
    private String ports;
}

@Data
public class ContainerId implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    private Service service;
}
```

What im trying to do is using ServiceRepository:

```
public interface ServiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Service, ServiceId>    {
}
```

to persist a service object:

```
public class SomeClass{

    @Autowired
    ServiceRepository serviceRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void insertServices(Service service) {
        serviceRepository.save(service); <- Exception HERE!
    }
}
```

The service object contain a Server which is already in the DB at server table, the service itself which is not in the db yet and a list of containers which are not in the db yet(and should also be persistant now).
The error im getting when doing that is:

> org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'a.servers.Server' for property 'server'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'a.servers.Server' for property 'server': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:453) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:246) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.setPropertyValue(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation$IdentifierDerivingDirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.setPropertyValue(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:358) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.getId(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:166) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation.isNew(AbstractEntityInformation.java:42) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.isNew(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:237) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:553) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at a.services.ServiceService.updateServices(ServiceService.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
>       at a.services.ServiceService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7cf24811.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at a.services.ServiceService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a987bcb2.updateServices() ~[classes/:na]
>       at a.agents.DataFetcher.fetch(DataFetcher.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'a.servers.Server' for property 'server': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>       ... 62 common frames omitted

i have spring -> jpa -> show-sql set to true in application.yml so i do get this log before it fails:

> Hibernate: select server0_.name as name1_1_, server0_.server_url as server_u2_1_ from server server0_

Created DB seems ok:

[image: DB Scheme]

Comment: Your reopsitory is wrong. You have, for some reason, a composed Id and not a String. Why do you need a composed ID (whereas you apparently wan't name to be unique, if not your `findByName` doesn't make sense. Also please post the full stacktrace and not just a snippet and make sure you are setting the properties correctly (they are bi-directional so you should set both sides).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, You are right i fixed the repository but i still get the same error. I need the compose id because two services from two servers can have the same name. same goes for container, two containers from two services can have the same name. the containers inside the service also point to the service as they should. updated the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with a similar composite key in my current project.
Maybe I'm wrong, but for me it seems that `@IdClass` only works if none of the `@Id` annotated properties are foreign keys.
I finally refactored my entities by using `@EmbeddedId` instead.

...

Actually I have one more idea: try adding the `@ManyToOne` annotation to `server` property in the `ServiceId` class too:

```
public class ServiceId implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "service", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Server server;
}
```

Comment: Adding relation to the id class didn't work. Will try using EmbeddedId and update. Thanks

Comment: EmbeddedId didnt work as well. end up changing the data model :\